# format of int value, change how it is displayed

Tags: java, string, spring, format, int

I am using this line of code to dispaly a string with an int value at the end of it.

```
<legend><spring:message code="time.createMonth.legend" arguments="${year}"/></legend>
```

The code is working but it is displaying the int lik a number "2,011" instead of "2011".

How can I format it so as it is displayed without the comma?

is there an easy way that i can just throw a cast or somehting? Like so?

```
"arguments="${(Sting)year}" or "arguments="${Sting.valueOf(year)}"    ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at NumberFormat:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: tried a few things on that page but it seems to be that spring doesn't like it. I'll give it another look after lunch! :D

Comment: I eventually got it, Your answer pointed me in the right direction :)

Comment: How exactly did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest would be:

```
arguments="${'' + year}"
```